# AgGrid custom date filter

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

AgGrid date filter is in the form of `mm/dd/yyyy`, but I want to change it to `yyyy/mm/dd` how can I do that?
The date filter is part of the grid's columnDefinition where I use `filter: 'agDateColumnFilter'`

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-date-component/

Comment: I am afraid you need to build custom date filter as cited above by @medley56. AG grid datefilter doesn't allow developers to change date format.

Answer (score 0):

Here You Can Filter Date Like That Using Moment...

```
 //For Filter
    filterValueGetter: (params: ICellRendererParams) => {
        return moment(params.data.date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    }
```